# Can someone help me vectorize / speed up this Matlab Loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, optimization, vectorization

```
correlation = zeros(length(s1), 1);
sizeNum = 0;
for i = 1 : length(s1) - windowSize - delta    
    s1Dat = s1(i : i + windowSize);
    s2Dat = s2(i + delta : i + delta + windowSize);
    if length(find(isnan(s1Dat))) == 0 && length(find(isnan(s2Dat))) == 0
        if(var(s1Dat) ~= 0 || var(s2Dat) ~= 0)
            sizeNum = sizeNum + 1;
            correlation(i) = abs(corr(s1Dat, s2Dat)) ^ 2;
        end            
    end

end
```

What's happening here:

1. Run through every values in s1. For every value, get a slice for s1
   till s1 + windowSize.
2. Do the same for s2, only get the slice after an intermediate delta.
3. If there are no NaN's in any of the two slices and they aren't flat,
   then get the  correlaton between them and add that to the
   correlation matrix.

Comment: Please explain or remove `if(correlation(i) > 0.85),end`

Comment: Alright, that's done. Is there any way to vectorize this? Sorry, I'm very new with Matlab.

Comment: what's `length(isnan(s1Dat))`? isn't it always the same as `length(s1Dat)`? what's going on in this code???

Comment: That's checking for the length of the NaN's in the s1Dat vector. So, it's not.

Let me edit this to show what I'm doing.

Comment: I hope that helps now.

Comment: @gran_profaci: You are not checking for nan. `length(isnan([nan,1]))` is 2, it is irrelevant if the values are nan or other.

Comment: If you want to count the number of NaN's in a matrix, one way is to use `sum(isnan(matrix))`

Comment: Always generate the correlation coefficient and check the result for NaN.  If any of the inputs are NaN, the output will be as well.

Comment: No, I simply want to check for the nans within the window and not the entire matrix. I'm handling / not caring for the NaN's... so I don't really understand how that might be an issue any more. But thanks for your advice! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand your code. `length(find(isnan(s1Dat)))~=0` is true if there exist `nan`. Thus the calculation outputs only nan? Can you provide some input data? Btw: use `any(isnan(s1Dat))` instead of `length(find(isnan(s1Dat)))`.

Comment: Done. Made the change! Thanks!

Comment: You may also be interested in the [nancorr File Exchange Submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35501-nancorr/content/nancorr.m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, I am trying to understand what is being asked.

Take some data:

```
N = 1e4;
s1 = cumsum(randn(N, 1)); s2 = cumsum(randn(N, 1));
s1(randi(N, 50, 1)) = NaN; s2(randi(N, 50, 1)) = NaN;
windowSize = 200; delta = 100;
```

Compute correlations:

```
tic
corr_s = zeros(N - windowSize - delta, 1);
for i = 1:(N - windowSize - delta)
  s1Dat = s1(i:(i + windowSize));
  s2Dat = s2((i + delta):(i + delta + windowSize));
  corr_s(i) = corr(s1Dat, s2Dat);
end
inds = isnan(corr_s);
corr_s(inds) = 0;
corr_s = corr_s .^ 2; % square of correlation coefficient??? Why?
sizeNum = sum(~inds);
toc
```

This is what you want to do, right? A **moving window correlation function**? This is a very interesting question indeed …

Comment: Yes it is. That's precisely what I'm doing. Just checking over the window to see if it's valid or not.

Comment: Oh, and I'm just getting the squared correlation since well, it handles -ve slopes.

Comment: Note that you don't need to check within the loop - you can do it outside, once the loop is complete. Same for the square, you can do it outside. Similarly, SizeNum can be obtained outside the loop. The use of `abs` is of no use if you are working with real numbers.

Comment: No! I have to check for a window... whether it has a NaN or not.

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me: you can check for NaNs *at the end of the loop* - why do you think you need to check *within the loop*?